# C# strange behavior with + operator

Tags: javascript, c#, c++

Can anyone tell me why the following statement evaluates to false?

```
bool myBoolean = .6 + .3 + .1 == .1 + .3 + .6; // false
```

It does the same thing in Javascript and C++.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic?

Comment: As a note, testing for float equality after any arithmetic is usually a bad idea

Comment: Use the right type `decimal`: `bool myBoolean = .6m + .3m + .1m == .1m + .3m + .6m;`

Comment: Never trust floating point equality comparisons. You can simplify your example as bool myBoolean = .1 == .1;

Comment: @CallumBradbury: i cannot reproduce what you say. `bool myBoolean = .1 == .1;` returns true for me. That's confusing because the highly upvoted duplicate-question also states that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Nb. I'm answering this question since it is also tagged C++</sub>

Due to float representation errors, in C++ the above yields false since the two float numbers aren't perfectly equal.

E.g. the internal representation for 0.1 is close to that value, but not exactly it

[image]

The same holds for C#.

Allow me to link a famous document that (imho) every programmer dealing with floating point arithmetic should read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

]Never trust the `Floating-Point Arithmetic`. During the conversion you can have a loss of precison. That's why the result is false. I suggest u try using the decimal type which stores numbers in decimal notation. Thus your numbers will be representable precisely.

[image]